# curvature tensor of symmetric spaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, symmetric-spaces

I'm trying to understand the following theorem about the curvature tensor of a symmetric space:

*Let* $R$ *the curvature tensor of the space* $G/K$ *corresponding to the Riemannian structure* $Q$ ,*then at the point* $o=\pi(0) \in G/K$

$R_o(X,Y)Z=-\left[\left[X,Y\right],Z\right]$ *for any* $X,Y,Z \in T_0(G/K)$

My concern is that if i consider a compact semisimple Lie group there is a natural structure of symmetric group with Riemannian structure given by the Cartan-Killing metric, that can be represented as $g_{ij}=c_{im}^n c^m_{jn}$ where $c_{ij}^k$ are the structure constant of the Lie algebra associated to the Lie group.

Such metric is left invariant and the multiplication is a transitive so in a chart i have
$g(X,Y)_x=g(L_x X_e, L_x Y_e)=g(X_e,Y_e)$
for any left invariant vector field. **So the metric is constant and that implies that the Christoffel symbols of such metric are $0$** and  i'm expecting the curvature tensor to be zero as well, but this would means that $\left[\left[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}\right],\mathfrak{g}\right]=0$ that is impossible beacause the Lie algebra is semisimple and so not solvable.

The part in bold  is where i think there is an error, but i can't figure out what this error is

Comment: The statement about Chistoffel symbols is plain wrong. You are probably misinterpreting what you are reading.

Comment: It's always good to think about simple concrete examples when you learn about new concepts. The simplest example of a symmetric space is the standard $2$-sphere. You should compute everything explicitly for that case.

Comment: @Deane thanks for the comment, but i have already did it. The difference is that the 2-sphere is not a Lie group. The problem is that my calculations show that the Cartan-Killing metric of a semisimple Lie group should be always flat.
As the comment of the rude person above you says my error has to be in the calculation of the Christoffel symbols.


PS i have calculated also the case of $SO(3)$, but still my confusion remains

Comment: Did you find SO(3) to be flat?

Comment: @Deane exactly, i think i'm misunderstanding something about how the Cartan-Killing metric is represented because it is the only place where there can be an error in my reasoning, now i will add some details on my calculations

Comment: Christopher symbols are Normandy defined for coordinate vector fields, which necessarily commute. Your vector fields do not commute.

Comment: @MoisheKohan but if the metric is constant shouldn't always be true that the Christoffel symbols are 0?

In particular taken a set of coordinates on $T_eG$, namely $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_{e}\}$ I can define a frame as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_{y}=(L_y)_* \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_{e}$ because my metric is left invariant i have that the Christoffel symbols with respect to this coordinate vector fields are $0$

Comment: @Marco, have you tried to write out carefully a proof of what you claim in your last comment? It suffices to note that a basis of left invariant vector fields on a nonabelian Lie group are *never* coordinate vector fields. Note that here when we say "coordinates", we mean coordinates on $G$ (or at least a neighborhood of $e$ and NOT coordinates on $T_eG$.

Comment: There are different notions of "constant", it depends on the moving frame. What you are doing is mixing up computations with noncommuting moving frame with formulas using coordinate frames. I suggest reading do Carmo, chapters 1, 2, 4.

Comment: Another note: Any Riemannian  manifold has on a neighborhood of each point a basis of vector fields with a “constant metric”. An example is  an orthonormal frame of vector fields.

Comment: Thanks anyone, now i understand what my error was. Indeed i was confusing commuting(coordinates) frames of the Lie groups and not commuting frames.